# Add CSS subclass with jQuery addclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, subclass, addclass

I'm trying to add a subclass to a class using jQuery, my CSS looks like this:

```
.block:nth-child(7) .permahover {
   top: 0 !important; 
   left: 0 !important;
   opacity: 0;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) !important;
      -ms-transform: translate(0, 0) !important;
          transform: translate(0, 0) !important
}
```

While this is the js code for reference:

```
$(".block:nth-child(7)").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".block:nth-child(7)").addClass("permahover");
});
```

If I delete the ".block:nth-child(7)" in the class name so it looks just like ".permahover" everything goes, but I need it to be a subclass.
I tried by replacing in the javascript ".addClass("permahover")" with ".addClass("block:nth-child(7) .permahover") but as expected it didn't work. Is there any way to solve this and if not, any workaround (even if it requires me not to use jQuery)?

Comment: You're aware that the CSS doesn't match the javascript? In the CSS, the space before the last class means something

Comment: Also inside the function, you can just use `$(this).addClass("permahover");` as you are changing the element the event is on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not add a pseudo-class to a `DOM` element. If you think about it, you'll understand that it would be impossible to add `:nth-child(7)` class to an element which is NOT the seventh child of its parent.

But for your problem you dont't even need it, you should just remove the space from before `.permahover`

```
.block:nth-child(7).permahover {
   top: 0 !important; 
   left: 0 !important;
   opacity: 0;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) !important;
      -ms-transform: translate(0, 0) !important;
          transform: translate(0, 0) !important
}
```

If you leave the space there, your `CSS` rule will match a child element with `permahover` class inside your 7th `.block`.

```
<div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block permahover"></div> <!-- .block:nth-child(7).permahover  { ... } -->
</div>

<div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="permahover"></div> <!-- .block:nth-child(7) .permahover { ... } -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And also don't duplicate the `jQuery` query:

```
$(".block:nth-child(7)").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass("permahover");
});
```

Or, If you'd like to add the `.permahover` class to a child element, you can do this:

```
$(".block:nth-child(7)").mouseenter(function () {
    $(" > *", this).addClass("permahover");
});
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't specified it, I'm aware that the element I was trying to work with was the 7th child and the HTML is very similiar to the one you wrote.
Anyway, removing the space worked perfectly. Couldn't imagine it was just that! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS rule specifies a `.block` class that is the 7th child that has a child element with class `.permahover`.  What I think you want is:

```
.block:nth-child(7).permahover { ... }
```

This specifies an element with both `.block` and `.permahover` classes that is a 7th child.